# python requests - обход загрузки на сайте

Tags: python, requests

есть сайт 2007.eljur.ru, с авторизацией.
Вот код:

```py
import requests
link = "https://2007.eljur.ru/authorize"
data = {
    'username': 'username',
    'password': 'password'
}
session = requests.Session()
responce = requests.post(link, data=data).text
profile = session.get('https://2007.eljur.ru/journal-app/')
print(profile.text)
```

Проблема в том, что будь-то пароль правильный или нет, мы всё равно получаем сайт с оглавлением "загрузка". Можно ли обойти это?

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как это сделать на  **requests** но для таких сайтов с логин панелью рекомендую использовать **selenium**
так будет проще, да и функционал выше

код я сделал, можете пользоваться

но для начала нужно скачать будет **chrome** последней версии и [chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/)

поместить **chromedriver** в папку с кодом

вот код:

```
from selenium import webdriver #pip install selenium и нужно скачать driver для chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
html = driver.get("https://2007.eljur.ru/authorize")

#ищем поле login и вводим
email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/main/div/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/input')
email.send_keys('admin')

#ищем поле password и вводим
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/main/div/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/div/input')
password.send_keys('admin')

#ищем и нажимаем на кнопку
LoginButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginviewport"]/div/div/form/div[2]/button')
LoginButton.click()


#получаем код страницы
source = driver.page_source

print(source)
```

если смог помочь, прошу пометить мой ответ как верный